# Need help to optimize slow filtering of ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, optimization, mvvm

I need help to optimize the filtering into 2 listviews.
The 2 grids have the same ItemsSource, and are not displayed in the same time : only as "Cards" or only as grid (Visibility collapsed alternately).
If I comment the listview as "Cards" the filtering in the listview as grid is fast. So the slow performance seems to be linked to the ListView as (homemade) "Card" even if its visibility is collapsed.
The Listview as Grid is a homemade CustomListView.

I have tried the virtualization on the ListView as "Card" :

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateGroups" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
     <VirtualizingStackPanel>
          <Card (...)>
     </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- Groups as Cards -->
<ListView x:Name="lvGroupsAsCards"

          (...)

          Visibility="{Binding vListViewAsCards}"

          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"

          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateGroups}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ocGroups}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding objSelectedGroup}"
          >

(...)

<!-- Groups as Grid -->
<CustomListView x:Name="lvGroupsAsGrid"
                
                (...)

                Visibility="{Binding vListViewAsGrid}"

                ItemsSource="{Binding ocGroups}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding objSelectedGroup}"
                >
```

Do you have an idea about how to optimize the header filtering in the homemade CustomListView ?

Thanks per advance for your help :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. It's not clear what you are doing, what the slow ListView is of the two. And what is CustomListView? Maybe you could try to rephrase some of your sentences. For example: *"If I comment the listview as "Cards""* - What does this mean? *"The __Listview as Grid__ is a homemade CustomListView"* - What does this mean? *"The 2 grids "* - Which two Grids? There isn't a even a single Grid in your code.

Comment: *"are not displayed in the same time : only as "Cards" or only as grid"* - It's really the *complete* question that doesn't make any sense. What is Cards, and of course the ominous Grid again. Please provide the complete minimal code that replicates your issue. No ellipsis please... Try to be precise with the terminology you use. Provide context related code e.g. CustomListView. If we can't review the problematic code how can we suggest improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualizingStackPanel should be used inside ItemPanelTemplate of ListView.
In your case, you are using it inside ItemTemplate which may cause a performance issue since it will create a bunch of instances of VirtualizingStackPanel which may impact the rendering performance.

Remove it from the ItemTemplateGroups dataTemplate.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateGroups" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
          <Card (...)>
</DataTemplate>
```

move VirtualizingStackPanel to the ItemsPanelTemplate

```
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

If it will help you, do not forget to mark my post as the answer:)

Comment: VirtualizingStackPanel by default behaves like a common StackPanel. The presence of a ScrollViewer alone enables the magic. Additionally, ListView already uses a VirtualizingStackPanel by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anton, if I put the "VirtualizingStackPanel" into "ItemsPanelTemplate" as you said I have best performance, that's what I was looking for :) . But What I need is WrapPanel instead of a StackPanel, I found a NuGet package from an unknown and I have "no rights" to add it to my solution, I will have to find another way to get a "Virtualizing" "WrapPanel". Thanks again for your perfect answer Anton !

Comment: Anton you have well understood my question :)

Comment: For the moment I use the **VirtualizingWrapPanel 1.5.7** of **s.baeumlisberger** https://www.nuget.org/packages/VirtualizingWrapPanel